# vue.js and Laravel - how do we integrate vue js with laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a project, can anyone tell me that how do we integrate the vue.js with laravel 5.6 , i know how to integrate the html file with laravel , but i don't know anything about vue.js , if you explain the little bit of the folder structure that would be appreciative. Thank You

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you should google and you will find a lot of materials, blogs & tutorials. this platform not provide suggestion, tools & technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Vue just template DSL. There is the Laravel doc to refer to. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-vue-components